# Characterization of support of positive regular Borel measures

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a positive Borel measure ona compact Hausdorff topological space. I am trying to prove the following:

Show that $x \in support(\mu)$ if and only if $\int_X f d \mu >0$ for every continuous $f: X \to  [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) > 0$.

My attempt: I could prove the ($\Rightarrow$) part. I only want to prove that if $x \in X$ is such that for every continuous $f$ with $f(x)>0$ satisfies $\int_X f d \mu >0$, then $x \in support(\mu)$. Suppose not. Then there exists an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $\mu(U_x)=0$. From this stage, how do I construct a function $f_x$ such that $f_x(x)>0$ but $\int_X f_x d \mu \leq 0$.

Comment: Is your space Hausdorff?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: Yeah. We can assume that.

Comment: You may wish to apply Urysohn's lemma to a pair of suitably chosen closed sets.

Comment: @SamM: Actually I am not that comfortable with topology. Can you please explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: You have found an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ which does not meet the support of $\mu$. Now you want a continuous function which does not vanish at $x$, but does vanish on the support of $\mu$. Certainly $X\setminus U$ is closed and contains the support of $\mu$. This is one set. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma.)

Comment: @SamM: But don't we need two disjoint closed sets for Urysohn's lemma?If $X \setminus U$ is one such set, other closed set should lie inside $U$. How do I ensure that?

Comment: Yes. The other has to be (carefully) chosen. Fortunately, because your space is compact Hausdorff, point sets are closed.

Comment: @SamM: I see now. Thus the function integrated on the support is zero since the function itself vanishes on the support. It produces a contradiction.

Comment: I've written a proof for your question. You were most of the way there, you just needed to apply Urysohn's lemma to some suitable sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick proof.

Let $x\in X$.
First suppose that $x$ is in the support of $\mu$. Let $f:X\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function with $f(x)>0$. Then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(y)>0$ for all $y\in U$. Then
$$
\int_X f\,d\mu\geq\int_U f\,d\mu>0.
$$
Now suppose that $x$ is not in the support of $\mu$. Let $K$ be the closed support of $\mu$. Then there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap K=\emptyset$. Set $E=X\setminus U$ and $F=\{x\}$. Then $E,F$ are disjoint closed sets in $X$. By Urysohn's lemma, there exists a continuous function $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(E)\subseteq\{0\}$ and $f(F)\subseteq\{1\}$. In particular, $f(x)>0$ and 
$$
\int_X f\,d\mu=\int_E f\,d\mu=0.
$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: It should be $\int_E f d \mu=0$.

Comment: you're quite right. I've updated my answer. There are, of course, other ways of doing this. I think this is quite instructive though.